# knockout.js: edit selected object

Tags: knockout.js

<strike>https://jsfiddle.net/7ueL5taw/36/</strike>

https://jsfiddle.net/7ueL5taw/38/

I have a list of objects displayed in `<select>`, I can select one and I want to achieve, that it's properties `a` and `b` are:

1. displayed in the next two `<selects>`
2. can be changed from those two `<selects>`

I'm halfway stuck in 1:

- my js console gives an error `TypeError: selected(...) is undefined`.
- The first `<select>` is updating when selecting one of the entries, but
  not the second, second one doesn't even have the  elements.
- <strike>when i change the value of the first , select the other element, select the first one again, the value of 'a' property is the original one, not the one I previously set.</strike>

Where are my mistakes? How can I achieve this

EDIT: small change solves the last problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set the value of your select to a property within an undefined observable `selected().b()`.

Quick fix: `selected() != null ? selected().a() : null`

```
  <select style="width: 20%" data-bind="enable: selected, options: a, optionsCaption: 'Choose...', value: selected() != null ? selected().a() : null">
  </select>
  <select style="width: 20%" data-bind="enable: selected, options: b, optionsCaption: 'Choose...', value: selected() != null ? selected().b() : null">
  </select>
```

See working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ueL5taw/39/)

Comment: omg, sometimes i'm just stupid....
luckily, in these cases the fixes are the easiest :) THX!

Comment: 2018 - still a great answer